# Concat input array based on desired length in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to concatenate input array based on specific length, Please help. In my case, I need to concatenate input values for the length <= 10, if its greater than 10, needs to go to next... Please check my input and expected result as below; Thank You.

Input = "Welcome","to","java","world","Thanks", "for", "visiting", "our", "World".

Expected Result = "Welcome to", "java world", "Thanks for", "visiting", "our world".

Comment: Please give a try and share the code where you got struck? stackoverflow won't work for your assignments.

Comment: Why "visiting" is not concatenating with "our"?

Comment: @Thrasher I think because `"visiting our"`'s length would be greater than ten.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a method to separate by length (i.e. 10)

### Main:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConcatArrayLength
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {
        String[] input = { "Welcome","to","java","world","Thanks", "for", "visiting", "our", "World"};

        String [] output = concatByLength (input,  10 ); //separate by 10

        for( String outputElement : output )
        {
            System.out.println ( outputElement );
        }

    }

    private static String [] concatByLength (String[] input, int separator )
    {

        List < String > listString = new ArrayList< String > ( );

        String concatElement = "";

        for ( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ )
        {
            //concat and trim
            concatElement = concatElement.concat ( input[i] + " " );
            concatElement.trim ( );
            //add if >= separator length
            if ( concatElement.length ( ) >= separator)
            {
                listString.add ( concatElement );
                concatElement = "";
            }
            //last element check
            else if( i == input.length-1)
            {
                listString.add ( concatElement );
            }
        }

        return listString.toArray ( new String[listString.size ( )] );
    }

}
```

### Example output:

Just change the line `concatByLength (input,  DESIRED_NUMBER );`

**10:**

```
Welcome to 
java world 
Thanks for 
visiting our 
World
```

**15:**

```
Welcome to java 
world Thanks for 
visiting our World
```

**30:**

```
Welcome to java world Thanks for 
visiting our World
```